# Error in checking an email id is valid using Mail::CheckUser

Tags: linux, perl, email, smtp, cpan

I am creating a script for checking mail id inbox exist or not (mail probing), i am using Mail::CheckUser module for this.But when i execute the code with a mail id like "somthing@yahooo.com" it shows the mail id exist ,but it does not exist in reality.
could you please suggest any solution for this

the code i am usig is given below

```
use Mail::CheckUser;
use Data::Dumper;

my $res =Mail::CheckUser::check_email('something_something@yahoo.com');
print $res."\n\n\n";
my $res1 = Mail::CheckUser::last_check();
print Dumper($res1)."\n\n";
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Add the content of $res1

Comment: $VAR1 = {
             'reason' => 'SMTP server accepts username',
             'code' => 0,
             'ok' => 1
            };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Mail::Checker seems to be unfit for Yahoo

It seems that it is impossible to test existence of yahoo mailbox without sending a test message. Yahoo seems to reject messages to non existing user in reply to "the final dot" in SMTP session.

I have tried to send message to non existing (long random) mailbox with the following result (bounce message):

```
<d5b980c9018f82c94cefee51193f8a61@yahoo.com>: host
 mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[98.138.112.32] said: 554 delivery error: dd This user
 doesn't have a yahoo.com account
 (d5b980c9018f82c94cefee51193f8a61@yahoo.com) [0] -
 mta1516.mail.ne1.yahoo.com (in reply to end of DATA command)
```